# changing between tv channels

Tags: expressions

If I want someone, who is holding the TV remote control, to change the channel on TV, then what should I tell him\her? (1) Switch to another channel? (2) move to another channel? (3) Go to another channel? (5) Turn to another channel? (6)Put on another channel on TV?

Comment: Any of those sound acceptable to me (a native American English speaker), though 6 sounds a bit off. "change channels" is how I would say it.

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("belongs on ELL"). Hi Mohammad, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move is not commonly used.

I would use most of them except 6

The easiest is:

> Switch to channel ______

Some other ways:

> Switch to another channel, please
>
> Change the channel, please
>
> Can you change channel, please

Comment: Thank you so much D. Manokhin, but does expression 6 still a valid expression, I mean is it correct to say it?

Comment: @MohammadAL-Shiyab it is but not commonly used

Comment: @MohammadAL-Shiyab no problem. If my answer helped feel free to press the tick next to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Go to channel 2 is easiest and most common. Switch to is acceptable. Move to is not used.